# As a contractor for an FBO, is it okay for us to transmit Internet signals right above the tarmac?

Tags: faa-regulations

I have been looking for the FAA Regulations on this with no luck, we are contracted IT with a local FBO and they want to provide internet to all their hangers. The easiest way would be to put a line of sight connector for the network so we can pass the internet over it, HOWEVER it will shoot over the TARMAC and I am not sure if FAA prohibits that. It is only for ground operations the Airplanes won't be using it but I just wanted to cover myself before I did it.

Comment: Won't the internet service be interrupted every time a plane lands?  What if (Murphy's law) a plane stops at Just The Right Spot?

Comment: Well it would be shooting about 15 ft above the largest planes that we can take at the airport

Comment: I think this would fall under FCC regulations rather than FAA regulations. I don't think the FAA even regulates aircraft-to-aircraft transmissions; that's the FCC's job. By the way, keep in mind that airplanes will occasionally be flying 15 feet *above* the ground, too; *any* space above a runway is space where aircraft occasionally go.

Comment: 15 feet above sounds good; momentary interruptions shouldn't be a problem.  Now about helicopters... :-)

Comment: While not an authoritative answer, I know many FBOs have been installing and expanding their WiFi coverage, (many pilots like to be able to file and brief from their iPads in the cockpit).  I've never heard of any concerns or limitations.  Also, many smaller airports are near neighborhoods that are absolutely saturated with multiple WiFi sources in every single household.

Comment: I didn't think about it falling under FCC, and the specific spot that we will be crossing is only where planes/helicopters land to load passengers so I am not worried about the planes being off the ground at that spot, although I did forget about Helicopters

Answer (score 3):

There are no FAA restrictions on setting up WIFI transmitters and receivers at an airport in the United States.

WIFI transmissions do not interfere with the frequencies used by airplanes for operational purposes.